# How do we recover the probability semigroup from the resolvent - A question concerning the paper from Holley Stroock 1976

Tags: markov-process, semigroup-of-operators

In the paper [A Martingale approach to Infinite Systems of Interacting Processes](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176996130) one reads:

[image]

To understand the proof we need to operate with relations in   (7.3) and (7.7).

Let' s have them here:

[image]

[image]

The definition of the resolvent is

$$R_\lambda f(\eta) = \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t} \Bbb{E} [f(\eta(t))]\, dt $$

we rely on the following relation stated in 7.7

> for $f$ well behaved
>    $$f(w) = \int_0^\infty  e^{-w t} \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\Gamma e^{zt} f(z)\, dz \, dt $$

We would like to see that

$$\Bbb{E} [f(\eta(u))] = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\Gamma e^{\lambda u} R_\lambda f (\eta) \, d \lambda $$

**Attempt**

First write

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\Gamma e^{\lambda u} R_\lambda f (\eta) \, d \lambda &
=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\Gamma e^{\lambda u} \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t} \Bbb{E} [f(\eta(t))]\, dt  \, d \lambda \\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t} \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma e^{\lambda u} \Bbb{E} [f(\eta(t))]  \, d \lambda\, dt
\end{align*}

But how to conclude from here?

---

For the sake of completeness

Here I add the relations 7.1 (a), (c) in case one imagines this might be helpful

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove this result, one should take the Fourrier transform of both sides of (7.9):

$$\tag{7.9} \Bbb{E}^{\Bbb{P}_\eta} [f(\eta(t))] = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\Gamma e^{ z t} R_z f (\eta) \, dz $$

For the left-hand side we obtain
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t}\Bbb{E}^{\Bbb{P}_\eta} [f(\eta(t))]\, dt = R_\lambda f(\eta)
\end{align*}
by the definition of $R_\lambda$.
For the right-hand side we obtain

\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t}\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\Gamma e^{z t} R_z f (\eta) \, dz \, dt = R_\lambda f(\eta)
\end{align*}
by (7.7) therefore the Laplace transform of these two functions is the same for $\lambda >1$